# Get ClassName from a css file

Tags: c#, css, .net, winforms

i'd like to get all the CSS-Class names from a CSS file.

My CSS File looks like this:

```
p.juicy{
    margin-left:40px;
}

p.csBody{
    text-align:justify;
}

p.csCode{
    font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    background-color:silver;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

I have this following code:

```
     string fileName = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(dir);

        MatchCollection mt = Regex.Matches(fileName, @"[^}]?([^{]*{[^}]*})", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mt.Count; i++)
        {
            string cls = mt[i].Captures[0].ToString().Trim();
            var className = cls.Substring(1, cls.IndexOf("{") - 1).Trim().Replace(":before", "").Replace(":after", "");

            list.Add(className);

        }
```

I'm not very familiar with regex. Is there an other work-around for this?

Thank you

Comment: does this help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335850/CSSParser??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is very good if you want to get strings out of regularly structured text but is quite poor when you need to "parse" stuff. In this case, it'll fall down if your file contains string literals which also happen to contain css-selctor structures within them. For example, you have a `content: ".im-a-word-with-a-space-afterwards {"`. It'll also have trouble if you forget to parse out pseudo selectors such as `.my-class:before` and combinations like `.one-class.another-class`.

If you know *for sure* the structure of the CSS your reading (e.g.  because it's *your* CSS) then I'd recommend sticking to your regex and bodging around edge cases. This will do fine for shorter jobs and internal one-off scripts.

If you need a super-robust solution to getting all class names then I'd either write a proper CSS parser (unwise) or get a previously available one such as [exCSS](https://github.com/TylerBrinks/ExCSS) which "understands" CSS well enough to extract out information like class names.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out. This will work.

```
MatchCollection mt = Regex.Matches(fileName, @"\.(.*?)\{", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

But is there a solution without using regex?